# Comparing only time values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to compare two time values .Like **from time** and **to time** . I am unable to achieve the requirement that, **to time** should be always greater than **from time**. 
I am using jquery time picker. please help I am a new bee .

Below goes my code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.timeselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/date-en-US.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.tp').timeselect({
            'step': 30,
            'format': 'HH:mm',
            autocompleteSettings: {
                autoFocus: true 
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="detail_items2" id="fromTimeDiv">
    <p><label id="fromTimeDiv_Label" for="fromTime_label" class="blue_text2">From Time <font style="color:red;">*</font></label></p>
    <input type="text"  class="tp" name="fromTime" id="fromTime" maxlength="75"  value=""   onKeyPress="document.getElementById('fromTime_error').innerHTML='';"/>
</div>
<div class="detail_items2" id ="toTimeDiv">
    <p><label id="toTimeDiv_Label" for="toTime_label" class="blue_text2">To Time <font style="color:red;">*</font></label></p>
    <input type="text" class="tp"  name="toTime" id="toTime" maxlength="75"  value=""   onKeyPress="document.getElementById('toTime_error').innerHTML='';"/>
</div>
```

For Date I'm comparing as below .Please help me in time i.e. To Time should always be greater than From Time

```
if(toDate<fromDate){
    alert("To Date should be greater than or equal to From Date");
    $("input#toDate").focus();
    return false;
}
if (fromTime == "") {
    $("label#fromTime_error").show();
    document.getElementById("fromTime_error").innerHTML="This field is Required.";
    $("input#fromTime").focus();
    document.getElementById("imageCheck").checked = false;
    return false;
}
if (toTime == "") {
    $("label#toTime_error").show();
    document.getElementById("toTime_error").innerHTML="This field is Required.";
    $("input#retoTimeco").focus();
    document.getElementById("imageCheck").checked = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you actually get the values of toTime and fromTime, are they null ?

Comment: no they arent .. fromTime = document.getElementById("fromTime").value;
        toTime = document.getElementById("toTime").value;

Comment: Yes but where in your code is this executed?

Comment: every thing is excuting .. can u please help out in time values